# The question is whether the two values of $I_2$ as obtained below are same?

Tags: integration

Integrate, $\int \frac{\sin^{2}{2\theta}}{2\cos{2\theta}}d\theta$

Let, $\sin2\theta=t$

then, ${2\cos2\theta} d\theta=dt$

$dt=\frac{1}{2}\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-t^2}}$

Integral =$\frac{1}{4}\int {\frac{t^2}{1-t^2}} dt$

Integral =$\frac{1}{4}\int {\frac{t^2}{1-t^2}} dt$

Integral =$-\frac{1}{4}\int {\frac{t^2-1+1}{t^2-1}} dt$

Integral =$-\frac{1}{4}\int ({1+\frac{1}{t^2-1}} )dt$

Integral =$-\frac{1}{4} (t+\int{\frac{1}{t^2-1}} dt)$

Integral =$-\frac{1}{4} (t+I_2)$

$I_2=\int \frac{1}{t^2-1}dt$

Now, $I_2=\frac{1}{2}\int (\frac{1}{t-1}-\frac{1}{t+1})dt$

Now, $I_2=\frac{1}{2}log(\frac{t-1}{t+1})+c_2dt$ ---(I)

we can also have the following,

$I_2=-\int \frac{1}{1-t^2}dt$

Now, $I_{2}=-\frac{1}{2}\int (\frac{1}{1+t}+\frac{1}{1-t})dt$

Now, $I_{2}=-\frac{1}{2}log(\frac{1+t}{1-t})+c_{22}$ ---(II)

The question is whether these two values of $I_2$ are same ? If, yes how do we show that both the values of $I_2$ as obtained in (I)&(II) are same ?

Comment: When you take the integral of $1/t$, you get $\log |t|+c$.

Answer (score 2):

They are the same, if you put in the necessary absolute value signs. Note that 
$$\log\frac{a}{b}=-\log\frac{b}{a}.$$

Without absolute value signs, the entries inside the log are of different signs, so at one of them the logarithm isn't even defined.

**Remark:** A perhaps more natural way to tackle the problem is to rewrite the top as $1-\cos^2 2\theta$. Then we are integrating $\frac{1}{2}\left(\sec 2\theta -\cos 2\theta\right)$.

In a sense, there is no real saving, since $\int \sec x\,dx$ is unpleasant. However, it may be one of the standard "memorized" integrals.

Answer (score 0):

A few things to point out:

1. $\int\frac{1}{x}dx=\ln|x|+C$.
2. $\ln\frac{a}{b}=-\ln\frac{b}{a}$.